# Cloud Function strange behaviour when downloading from storage bucket

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, google-ai-platform

I download my image from my cloud bucket with (python):

```
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('mybucket')
blob = bucket.blob('myimage.png')
img = blob.download_as_bytes(raw_download=True)
```

Then using tensorflow, I convert the image to a tensor, and return the shape of the image back.

```
image = tf.io.decode_image(img, dtype = tf.dtypes.float32)
image = tf.expand_dims(image, axis=0)

shape = image.shape
return {"1":shape}
```

When I test the function, I receive {1": "<'unknown'>"}, where as if I run the code on my local machine I will receive the actual shape of the tensor/image (1, 224, 224, 3). I don't understand why this works on my local machine, but not on the cloud function.

Comment: And you don't have issue/error? It's like if there is an error. Maybe because there are dependencies not installed or not compliant

Comment: I don't have any issue/error- only get returned back this 'unknown' which should be a tensor's shape. Since I've posted though I've investigated more and I think it is because of the function tf.io.decode- I index into the img bytes and return these correctly, eg return img[0] I recieve the byte value, but if I instead return image[0,0,0] I receive 'stridedslice0'

Comment: I am not sure why this function will not work though- I specified runtime 2.4 which includes tensorflow 2.4. This should include tf.io

Comment: To clarify, I recieve {
  "predictions": "Tensor(\"strided_slice:0\", shape=(), dtype=float32)" }

Comment: I've figured it out, eager execution seems to be disabled by default in this cloud enviroment. So calling tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution() before solves the problem. Strange why this is disabled by default though...

Answer (score 1):

From comments

> Eager execution seems to be disabled by default in this cloud
> environment. So calling `tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()` before
> solves the problem (paraphrased from waltwhite)

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()

image = tf.io.decode_image(img, dtype = tf.dtypes.float32)
image = tf.expand_dims(image, axis=0)

shape = image.shape
return {"1":shape}
```